# CucumberOptions, json-pretty disappered

Tags: java, cucumber

With Cucumber 1.1.2 I use the following annotation in my CucumberTest.java:

```
@Cucumber.Options(
  features = { "blabla",
    "src/test/resources/nl/abz/automotive/messaging/cucumber/via-aims-pil.feature"},
  format = {"html:target/cucumber-html-report-via-ams", "json-pretty:target/cucumber-report-via-ams.json" },
  glue = { "blabla" })
```

In Cucumber 1.2.2 format is replaced by plugin, but "json-pretty" is disappeared. What should I use to get json output?

Answer (score 1):

It is too simple: "json-pretty" is replaced by "json" without "pretty".